# Has Derek Parfit been working on time since 2011?

Tags: time, analytic-philosophy

The New Yorker published a [portrait](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2011/09/05/how-to-be-good) of Derek Parfit in 2011, which included this outlook:

> The first paper Parfit wrote after he began to study philosophy was on
>   the metaphysics of time. Now this is the subject to which he plans to
>   return.

However, the following paragraphs all referred to arguments (time passing metaphorically like a spot-light, bias toward the future perhaps caused by natural selection) that seemed familiar from [*Reasons and Persons*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasons_and_Persons) (published in 1984), and thus apparently not-new.

So my question is this: has Derek Parfit circulated or published anything on time since 2011 and/or is he known to work on a third major project perhaps in this area?

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you, but thank you for the piece on Parfit. I hadn't known of it before, really terrific read.

Comment: It does not look like it : http://philpapers.org/s/parfit